# GWT UiBinder NullPointerException

Tags: java, gwt

I'm getting a NPE when trying to use UiBinder.  The first time I used it, it worked great.  So I figured I would try to move another page over to UiBinder but I get this exception with no explanation why.  I've removed everything that could be causing any errors...yet the exception persists.  This is what is left of my code.  The code worked fine before I tried to make it use UiBinder.  The very first thing it complained about was that I didn't have an empty constructor.  My other file doesn't either...and it does not complain about that one at all.  Am I not allowed to have 2 classes that use UiBinder in the same package?  I'm at a loss as to why one works and the other doesn't.

MalfunctionViewPage.java

```
import com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MalfunctionViewPage extends Composite {
    interface MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MalfunctionViewPage> {}
    private static MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MalfunctionViewPage.class);

    public MalfunctionViewPage() {
       initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

MalfunctionViewPage.ui.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
TEST
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And my oh so helpful exception:

```
12:01:15.374 [ERROR] [mypackage.JobWorkbook] Failed to create an instance of 'mypackage.client.MalfunctionViewPage' via deferred binding 

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at mypackage.client.MalfunctionViewPage.&lt;init&gt;(MalfunctionViewPage.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:480)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:72)
at mypackage.client.MalfunctionViewPage.&lt;clinit&gt;(MalfunctionViewPage.java:10)
at mypackage.client.Main.changeScreen(Main.java:223)
at mypackage.client.Main.onValueChange(Main.java:151)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.EventBus.dispatchEvent(EventBus.java:40)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:87)
at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:94)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.newItem(HistoryImpl.java:138)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:210)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:195)
at mypackage.client.PageName.switchTo(PageName.java:42)
at mypackage.client.LoginPage$4.onSuccess(LoginPage.java:118)
at mypackage.client.LoginPage$4.onSuccess(LoginPage.java:1)
at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:232)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:259)
at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:356)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: try to replace TEST (MalfunctionViewPage.ui.xml) for  <g:FlowPanel></g:FlowPanel>

Comment: I have tried <g:HTMLPanel>TEST</g:HTMLPanel> with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at below line where argument class name and assigned type are not same.

```
private static MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MalfunctionViewPage.class);
```

It should be

```
private static MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder.class);
```

Complete code:

```
public class MalfunctionViewPage extends Composite {
    @UiTemplate("MalfunctionViewPage.ui.xml")
    interface MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MalfunctionViewPage> {
    }

    private static MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(MalfunctionViewPageUiBinder.class);

    public MalfunctionViewPage() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}
```

In ui.xml `TEST` is not valid without any outer container. It results into

```
ERROR - Unexpected text in element: "TEST": <ui:UiBinder>
```

Try with some container such as HTMLPanel.

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <g:HTMLPanel>TEST</g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```